# AngularJS RSS feed reader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rss

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.ivivelabs.com/blog/making-a-quick-feed-reader-using-angularjs/) for how to create a reader, but it doesn't seem to be working. Specifically, the `$http.jsonp(...)` call does not seem to work. It hangs for about 20 seconds and then simply returns a GET error.

This is the full Angular code.

```
var app = angular.module('RSSFeedApp', []);

app.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope','FeedService', function ($scope,Feed) {    
    $scope.loadButonText="Load";
    $scope.feedSrc="http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news";

    $scope.loadFeed=function(e){        
        Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function(res){
            $scope.loadButonText=angular.element(e.target).text();
            $scope.feeds=res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        });
    }
}]);

app.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        parseFeed : function(url) {
            return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&amp;num=50&amp;callback=JSON_CALLBACK&amp;q='+ encodeURIComponent(url));
        }
    }
}])
```

Is there a different/better way to do RSS feeds in angular, or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

My app was not yet hosted out on any external server, it is instead currently just running off my machine and I'm accessing the file location through a browser.

ex:

```
file:///C:/Users/...
```

The jQuery call to `//ajax.googleapis...` then routed to a file location, rather than the web address. Changing `//ajax.googleapis...` to `https://ajax.googleapis...` fixed this.

Simple mistake but easy to overlook I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a module and provided an example of for integrating the Google Feed API in your AngularJS app.  You can check out the article [here](http://www.vizuri.com/insights/blog/2014/03/including-blog-rss-feed-your-angularjs-app).